# EnableApiKeySupport generates error

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

while trying to Add bearer token using Swashbuckle swagger-document

i got this error in SwaggerConfig.cs
**swaggeruiconfig does not contain definition for 'EnableApiKeySupport'**

[image: error]

do any body know what may be the reason

**Update**

this is the entire swagger.config

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace AppNameSpace
{
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.ApiKey("Token")
                     .Description("Filling bearer token here")
                     .Name("Authorization")
                     .In("header");

                    c.SingleApiVersion("v2", "AppNameSpace");

                    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());


                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");


                });
    }
    protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format(@"{0}\bin\AppNameSpace.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That should work just fine! Can you paste your entire SwaggerConfig.cs in the question...

Comment: Also what version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: Swashbuckle version 5.6.0

Comment: I just tested your GlobalConfiguration on a new project and ***EnableApiKeySupport*** works fine for me...

Comment: what versions of Swashbuckle,Swashbuckle.Core,Swashbuckle.Core.Extension are you using ? there may be some conflict with me

Comment: I'm going to upload my test project to GitHub... yes I'm afraid this might be something on your end...

Comment: Here is my test: https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/tree/master/WebApi560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I believe is something on your project outside Swashbuckle, I created a test project with your GlobalConfiguration and it compiles without any error:
https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/tree/master/WebApi560

On that test project I'm using the following packages:

```
<package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

You can try seeing what options are available for the SwaggerUiConfig...
in your VisualStudio project remove the EnableApiKeySupport and let the IntelliSense show you what's available, you should see something like:

[image]

If yours does not look like the one on my picture. You might be overwriting the class SwaggerUiConfig.

Comment: Solved by adding a reference for Swashbuckle.Core , the reference was missing although the package is installed correctly, your demo helped a lot, thank you very much.